# PHP: My elseif statement is ignored

Tags: php, if-statement

My `elseif` statement is being ignored. The `if` and `else` work but `elseif` doesn't.

```
if ($location === "Canterlot") {
    echo "you cannot add a thread here...";
} elseif ($admin === "3") {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
       <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
       </form>';
} else {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
       <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
       </form>';
}
```

Comment: $admin is string 3 or integer 3?

Comment: What is the value of `$admin`?

Comment: put $location and $admin value in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**note that**

*The == operator just checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But, the === operator actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type.*

I think You have some thing like this:

```
  $location = "Canterlot" and $admin ="3";
```

So it will have first condition true(`$location == "Canterlot"`)  and it  never check `else if ($admin =="3")`

You can try something like this:

```
   if($location === "Canterlot" && $admin !== "3"){
echo "you cannot add a thread here...";
}else if ($admin === "3"){
echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
    <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>';
}else{
echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
    <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>';
}
```

Update:

If  `$admin` is intteger then check like this:

```
 if($location === "Canterlot" ){
    echo "you cannot add a thread here...";
    }else if ($admin == "3"){
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
        <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
    </form>';
    }else{
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="thread_name" value="comment">
        <textarea name="thread"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
    </form>';
    }
```

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt: it should be work. get value of $admin . If it is integer then try last one if string then try first one.

Comment: Your first paragraph is crap; `===` isn't used for "just string comparison". The triple equals operator checks for equality **and type** when comparing things, as opposed to doing a fuzzy check when using `==`

Comment: @Bojangles : thanks :) i was not rightly described it(i am poor in english). Now i have edited my question with full description.

Answer (score 3):

`$admin` is a `string`:

```
($admin === "3")
```

`$admin` is an `int`:

```
($admin === 3)
```

Please try [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php) **and check `$location` value**.

Answer (score 0):

```
($admin === "3")
```

should be

```
($admin == "3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this:

```
<?php

$location = 'foo';
$admin = '3';

if ($location === "Canterlot") {
    echo 'didn\'t get it';
} elseif ($admin === '3') {
    echo 'got it';
} else {
    echo 'didn\'t get it';
}
```

And the output is `got it`. See [here](http://codepad.org/iIdPLSgI).

With:

```
<?php

$location = 'foo';
$admin = 3;

if ($location === "Canterlot") {
    echo 'didn\'t get it';
} elseif ($admin === 3) {
    echo 'got it';
} else {
    echo 'didn\'t get it';
}
```

The output is `got it` as well.

Please check the rest of your code.