# PHP Comparison elseif ignoring if

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

For some reason, I can't get this to work, and also if there is a better way to be doing this, please share :)

```
    <?php $or->billing['street_address'] = "123 Nowhere St";
      $or->billing['city'] = "Somewhere"; 
      $or->billing['postcode'] = "92702";
      $or->billing['state'] = "CA";
      $or->shipping['street_address'] = "123 Nowhere St";
      $or->shipping['city'] = "Somewhere"; 
      $or->shipping['postcode'] = "92702";
      $or->shipping['state'] = "CA"; 
      ?>

Billing: <a href="...&street=<?php echo $or->billing['street_address']?>&where=<?php echo $or->billing['postcode']?>"> <?php echo $or->billing['street_address'].', ' .$or->billing['city'].', ' .$or->billing['state']. ' ' .$or->billing['postcode']; ?></a>

Shipping: <a href="...&street=<?php echo $or->shipping['street_address']?>&where=<?php echo $or->shipping['postcode']?>"> <?php echo $or->shipping['street_address'].', ' .$or->shipping['city'].', ' .$or->shipping['state']. ' ' .$or->shipping['postcode']; ?></a>

<?php 
if ($or->billing['street_adddress'] == $or->shipping['street_address'] )  { 
echo "Billing/Shipping Match";
} elseif ($or->billing['postcode'] == $or->shipping['postcode']) {
echo "ZIP codes Match";
} else 
{
echo "Different Billing/Shipping ZIP codes";
}

?>
```

Not sure why it doesn't recognize that what should be echoed is "Billing/Shipping Match", not "ZIP codes Match". Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

And I have already tried adding something like

```
&& ($or->billing['street_adddress'] != $or->shipping['street_address'])
```

to the elseif, it still didn't work ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934688/php-my-elseif-statement-is-ignored))

Anyone have any ideas? Oh, and I edited the URL's just so it's cleaner but it's linking to whitepages.com. Just want to check to see if the customers billing and shipping address match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra 'd' in street_address.

```
if ($or->billing['street_adddress'] == $or->shipping['street_address'] )
                            ^
```

Its displays `Undefined index: street_adddress`

Comment: Thanks! I actually read over that three times to make sure I didn't have a spelling error, but I still missed it!